# Looking for .equals()

Tags: equals

Basically, what I'm looking for is a counter argument to the .equals() command for strings. Is there a command that would be the equivalent opposite like .notEquals()? I basically need to compare a string to user input, and if the user input isn't correct I want to print something.

Comment: Hmm.. what about `.equals() == false`? (didn't specify a language so I assume C-based).

Comment: It looks like you aren't informed yet. Time to change that: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: What language is this... c# perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but in what language?

In Java & C# you can use:

`!StringInput.Equals("ValueToCompare");`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the "!" operator.
Like this:

```
if(!string_var.equals(other_string)){
    //here you put the code if the string is not equal to
}else{
    //here you put the code if the string IS EQUAL to
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a the `!` the negation boolean operator applied to the result of `.equal`.

that is just like saying NOT equal